# store the rest of a successive division in a array

Tags: c

I want to create a program who store the rest of successive division in the array.But unfortunately the array i created refuse store the remain correctly for example 5/2 the remain is suppose to be 1 but the array store another value

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int divise(int n){
    int i=0;
    int remain[20];
    int rest;
    while(n!=0){
        rest = n%2;
        remain[i] = rest;
        n = n/2;
        i++;
        printf("%d\n",remain[i]);
    }
}

int main(){
    divise(10);
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to get a binary representation of a number?

Comment: yes that's what i want to do

Comment: What is the expected output of your example program, and the actual output?

Comment: `printf` the value *before* you increment `i`.

Answer (score 1):

The mistake is with your `i++` statement . It should be after `printf("%d\n",remain[i]);`.

Modified code :-

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int divise(int n)
{
    int i = 0;
    int remain[20];
    int rest;
    while (n != 0)
    {
        rest = n % 2;
        remain[i] = rest;
        n = n / 2;
        printf("%d\n", remain[i]);
        i++;                        // repositioned 
    }
}
int main()
{
    divise(10);
    return 0;
}
```

**Output :-**

```
0
1
0
1
```

Your function `int divise(int n)` do not return any int values . So better make it `void divise(int n)` .Also `int main()` should have a `return 0` .

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that `main()` should return 0, and `divise()` should return `void` instead of `int`.

Comment: @frslm thanks for notify that.